# revise jquery ajax into native react methos

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-native, react-async

how can I remove the jquery-ui ajax in react for some other ajax method. I am fetching data from json file and need to show the data in the html page.

```
var app = React.createClass({
 loadAppData: function() {
    $.ajax({
     async: false,        
      url: this.props.url + '/json/app.json',
      dataType: 'json',           
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('successfull');
        jdata = data;
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Comment: i like fetch() myself, but i don't think it supports sync.

Comment: yeah read about fetch a bit, and it doesnt support certain browsers too.